# Flutter grpc streaming

Tags: flutter, grpc

Is there any way to create infinite scrolling using grpc streaming? So, I don't want to load all the data at one time and I don't want to do a standard pagination (unless it's the only way to do it) but I want to read data from stream in parts on user interaction. Any ideas?

UPD:
As I read from [official docs](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

> A stream is a sequence of asynchronous events. It is like an asynchronous Iterable—where, instead of getting the next event when you ask for it, the stream tells you that there is an event when it is ready.

So, the streams won't work that way I want.